# A page of our website appear HTTPS and not HTTP on Google research ( under only one keyword )

Tags: wordpress, ssl, server

I have a really strange issue with the WordPress website with I'm working with

Under this research:
Best Barber Shop in Stillorgan

Our website appears with this link
https://mensgrooming.ie/contact-us/

The problem is that we don't use HTTPS but HTTP....

I tried to redirect in .htacces but is not working, how can I do?

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but you *should* get yourself an ssl certificate.  Your site visitors deserve it.  There really isn't any business reason I can think of to *not* have one and there are a ton of great reasons to get one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably not with your site, but with how Google sees your site. Most likely, there are one or more websites out there that link to your website using a url prefixed with https.  You can verify this using google's webmaster tools:  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/55281?hl=en

My first suggestion would be to just get an ssl cert for your site.  But if you are committed to not using ssl, then you should find the sites that are linking to you using https and request that they use http instead.  It won't change the links that Google uses right away, but eventually the https links to your site will sink in the ratings.

Comment: Thanks to answering,
I checked and there are no links directing to us on this page....
I guess We will go for the SSL certificates, but I wanted to understand how this can happen